# Is there such a tool on CentOS/SELinux to monitor incoming HTTP/HTTPS traffic the way Ngrok displays it?

Tags: centos7, selinux

I really love how ngrok displays the incoming connections to a server with the response. Is there such a tool (either to install or native) on CentOS/SELinux that would display some info? I found a tutorial for tcpflow but i was not impressed.

Thanks

[HTTP connection summary/dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSMat.jpg)

Comment: For the shell only or with gui for the desktop?

Comment: Maybe tcpdump or tshark?

Comment: Check this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19485/how-to-monitor-incoming-http-requests

Comment: tcpdump indeed, you might need to decrypt the ssl traffic

Comment: Ok i will stick with tcpdump then, thanks guys. Can someone answer the question so i can accept that as a valid answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tcpdump` would show your traffic, `tail -f <logfile>` would show hits on your webserver. `ngrok` is a proxy by itself, so you will need internal tools from the services you are using to display internal stuff.